# Creating an error in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

How would I check the JSON for a property and if it's missing return an error exiting and catching the chain?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

fs.readFileAsync("myfile.json").then(JSON.parse).then(function (json) {
    if (!json.prop) return new Error("missing prop");
    return json;
}).catch(SyntaxError, function (e) {
    console.error("file contains invalid json");
}).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function (e) {
    console.error("unable to read file, because: ", e.message);
});
```

Example taken from [bluebird documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#expected-and-unexpected-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make use of the `typeof` operand, catch undefined and throw/catch like the other errors, specifically you could make use of the `ReferenceError` type in your case:

```
fs.readFileAsync("myfile.json").then(JSON.parse).then(function (json) {
    if (typeof json.prop === "undefined") throw new ReferenceError("missing prop");
    return json;
}).catch(SyntaxError, function (e) {
    console.error("file contains invalid json");
}).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function (e) {
    console.error("unable to read file, because: ", e.message);
}).catch(ReferenceError,function(e){
    //handle the error
});
```